# Questions about effective divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular variety, and let $D$ be a divisor on $X$.
If there exists $n>0$ such that $nD$ is effective, then $D$ is also effective.

I think this is obviously true because if we write $D= \sum n_iY_i$, then for any $i$, $nn_i> 0$ implies $n_i> 0$.
Therefore the following corollary is weird to me:

> (Hartshorne Corollary 1.8 in Chapter V.)
> Let $X$ be a surface, which means a nonsingular projective surface over an algebraically closed field $k$, let $H$ be an ample divisor, and let $D$ be a divisor such that $D.H> 0$ and $D^2> 0$.
> Then for all $n\gg 0$, $nD$ is effective.

I'm confused about why we need the condition $n\gg 0$.
I can follow the proof where we use the Riemann-Roch theorem to get an inequality about $l(nD)$, so I know why we need it in the process.
However, if the above statement is true, then we could say more.
Why didn't he mention $D$ is also effective?

I should get something wrong, but I couldn't find it.
Any comments are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: In my copy, the corollary reads “$nD$ is *linearly equivalent* to an effective divisor”.

Comment: You are right. But at the end of the proof, he wrote "In particular, $nD$ is effective for all $n\gg 0$", so I questioned as above. Your comment helps me. The correct corollary is true, and I'm also correct but the last sentence of the proof is a little bit vague. Right?

Comment: I believe that the last sentence is incorrect. I think Hartshorne is using the criterion “linearly equivalent to an effective divisor iff $l >0$” and then forgot the linear equivalence part.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm not confident in my knowledge, and I'm worried about minor errors so often. Your comment really helps me.